# Using Field Service lightning objects in a custom application

Tags: servicecloud, field-service-lightning

I have to build a time-tracking application on salesforce. The customer already uses service cloud and intends to implement Field service lightning soon. Idea is to have this time tracking feature for all service cloud users. Some of the users may use salesforce only for entering time sheets.
I do not have sufficient knowledge of FSL. I did some research and found there is a time-tracking feature in FSL. There are timesheet and absence objects
The time sheet object is tied to Service Resource. I wanted to understand if I could reuse the absence and timesheet objects in my custom application. This is so that the field service user's and other service cloud user's timesheet data stays in the same object.

- Will the other users (non-field users )need any FSL license?
- Will I have to create service resource records for non-field users too?

Comment: Unless you make your package depend dynamically on these objects, with the ability to use alternative ones (you could do this via custom metadata), your package would require FLS licenses and would require the same representation for everyone recording time. This is probably not something you want to do. Providing a dynamic mapping is a nice solution to allow re-use of existing objects, but will make your package a lot more complex. You would also need to include your own objects, for when you don't have other objects available to use (because they are not installed on the org).

Comment: Thanks Phil. I am not intending to make a package since this is an implementation. I wanted to avoid mapping so that there is no duplication of data and consuming more storage space.

Comment: OK. Still, to use those objects I think you will find the users require access and thus licenses.